# Typescript/Javascript: Default for Map-miss

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to define a default result (anything else then undefined) for a maps get if it does not find the key in the map?

```
    let m = new Map <string,string> ([["1","a"],["2","b"]]);
    let r = m.get ("a");
    if (r===undefined)
    {
        r="NO";
    }
```

Normally it returns undefined and I need to check that. Is it possible to shortcut that?

Something like

```
r = m.get ("x") or "NO";
```

possible??

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have said `or`, so use `or` operator. Example is provided in Javascript.

```js
let m = new Map([["1","a"],["2","b"]]);
let r = m.get("a") || 'No';

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Oh dear, thats was too obvious. Thanks!